# How can I implement an Excel custom format with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to write JavaScript code that acts like Excel custom formatting: taking a format and applying it to a string/number/etc in a HTML table.

Is there some code or library that'll let me do that? I'm not trying to access Excel files, just copy the custom format functionality.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs then please use a framwork that can handle the excel operations. With that you can easily manipulate Excel files. There is one here try it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not accessing Excel files, so, at least the one you linked, won't suffice. It does work, but I don't see a way to get the formatted text, I can just set its value and format, so I assume it'll only be displayed on the potential Excel sheet, which I'm not using.

Comment: You can create with this too.